# Apache modrewrite rule for redirect from a dynamic .asp to main url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm on a linux server now and have moved from a .asp environment cms and now need to redirect old .asp urls from about 20 pages that look like this:  http://www.iwanet.org/argomento.asp?cat=38  and want it to redirect to http://iwanet.org/profdevel . There are several unique id's (cat=22, cat=2, cat=1 ) after the iwanet.org/argumento.asp? is the same so just need everything after the question mark ?=  so I need a catch-all redirect url for everything after the equal sign.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?argomento\.asp$ /profdevel [QSA,R=301,L]
```

This will route all requests to `/argomento.asp` to `/profdevel` with a 301 redirect and append the query string (with `QSA` flag).